# Symfony Set null children of entity when it's deleted

Tags: php, symfony, cascading-deletes

I have two entities Category and Product in a OneToMany relation. I would like to set null products when I delete their parent category.

I tried on the product entity :

```
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $category;
```

but it doesn't work.
How can I delete the category safely ?

Comment: Did you update your DB schema? You can do it either with `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` or with Doctrine Migrations. If you did, are you getting any exception or are the products deleted when you delete a category?

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the missing thing.